# How to remove � this symbol from one column in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 6000 rows in a table out of which almost 2000 rows having this symbol how I can find and replace this ?? Please help.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: It's probably an encoding issue. You'll have to give more context. Post your code both for inserting and retrieving. Show the full text of the value that contains the � symbol.

Comment: If the content is already screwed up and actually contains that symbol, you can search for it like any other character. Otherwise you probably just have a problem with *displaying* the content.

Comment: Thanks Mark and Deceze, I am having e-commerce web site and this symbol is in product description and need to remove it.. on the database level this character is not recognize but when I search for non ASCII character rows it gives me the rows which having this issue. select * from table where column regexp '[^ -~]'; this query gives me row which has problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `col` = REPLACE( `col`, '�', '' );
```

where `�` is to be replaced with the symbol.

Comment: The � character appears almost always only when there's an encoding issue. Running this would do nothing as � is not actually in the database but represents a character that cannot be displayed.

Comment: Juhana, you are right but in database this symbol stored as non ascii character.    select * from table where column regexp '[^ -~]'; gives me rows which having issue..  any clue to to get in that row replace?